# Flickering issue with a AWT / SWT component

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, swt, awt

I have a simple flickering problem with a AWT component in eclipse.
Here's my "hierarchy":

1. `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite` => main Parent received by my ViewPart object (in `createPartControl()`)
2. `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite` => a child of the main Parent with behavior `SWT.EMBEDDED`
3. `java.awt.Frame` => an awt Frame created with the bridge function `SWT_AWT.new_Frame()` (child of 2.)
4. `javax.swing.JComponent` => my final display (child of 3.)

All is working fine and I can manipulate my JComponent view. The size is ok but the view is flickering/blinking all the time.
It should be noted that before, I used a JPanel as a child of 3. and then the JComponent. With this alternative solution, the size wasn't ok but I wasn't getting any flickering.

Is there a way to solve this or at least some hints to understand this behavior ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

[EDIT: I have found a solution to the problem by keeping the intermediate JPanel and playing with the Layouts. I am still interested in understanding the pathological behavior]

Comment: curious: why do you mix swt and swing components? Most probably (don't know, just guessing :-) they have different threading rules, so mixtures are expected to be tricky to handle

Comment: Actually, I want to display a view created by the prefuse library, which returns me a subclass of JComponent. The only solution that I found was to bridge swt -> awt and then put my swing component in my awt. However, this works fine when I insert a JPanel between the JComponent and the Frame but I have layout issues in this case. That's why I think there should be a very easy solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

enable double buffering on your JComponent:

```
component.setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

Comment: JComponent.setDoubleBuffered(true); is default value in API for all nested and inherits methods from JComponent in Swing (excluding Top-Level Containers)

Comment: Actually this works for me, since I added a piccolo PCanvas directly to the Frame. And the PCanvas is derived directly from JComponent without setting the setDoubleBuffered flag within the constructor.